# How to use the corollary (manifold version rank theorem) to prove the quoted theorem?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

The outline is actually already given in [*Topics in DG*](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/dgbook.pdf) by Michor. To prove the following:

> 1.15. Theorem. Let $M$ be a connected manifold and suppose that $f : M →
> M$ is smooth with $f\circ f = f$. Then the image $f(M)$ of $f$ is a submanifold
>   of $M$.

The author proposes to find an open neighbourhood $U$ of $f(M)$ such that the derivative $T_xf$ has constant rank throughout $U$. Now I understand how this is done. But I don't know how to use the following corollary, as the author instructs, to complete the proof:

> Corollary. Let $f : M → N$ be $C^∞$ with $T_xf$ of constant rank $k$ for all
>   $x ∈ M$.
>   Then for each $b ∈ f(M)$ the set $f^{−1}(b) ⊂ M$ is a submanifold of $M$ of
>   dimension $\text{dim}M − k$.

I feel that he hints us to represent $f(M)$ via sets of the form of $f^{-1}(b),\,b\in f(U)=f(M)$, but I don't think it is possible. Am I missing something?

My thoughts: at each $x\in f(M)$, find a chart $(U,\phi)$ of $M$ centered at $x$, then $g: U\to M, g(y) = \phi^{-1}(\phi(f(y))-\phi(y))$ satisfies that $g^{-1}(x)=f(M)\cap U$. So $f(M)\cap U$ is a submanifold of $M$ by the corollary. Now how to get a global result?

PS I don't think this is the right track, since I feel the very purpose of introducing the rank theorem here is to avoid using charts.

PPS my thoughts are totally absurd since $g$ doesn't have the constant rank property any more, in fact it totally vanishes inside $f(M)$.

---

I'm NOT asking for proof of the corollary, but for how to use the corollary to prove the theorem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think that this corollary, as stated, is sufficient to prove the result, at least when directly applied to $f$. I would rather use the 'full' constant rank theorem (which implies the stated corollary as was pointed out in a now deleted answer from another 'stackexchanger'). Indeed, the 'full' constant rank theorem gives a local normal form for the map $f$, $(x_1, \dots, x_m) \mapsto (x_1, \dots, x_k, 0, \dots, 0)$. In your question, as $f(M) = Fix(f)$, you have that locally $Fix(f)$ is the fixed point set of the normal form, which is clearly the set $x_{k+1} = \dots = x_m = 0$.

Comment: What is $Fix(M)$? Also, the problem is that the normal forms given by the rank theorem are only locally defined, and I'm just struggling to paste them together. As shown in my thoughts, I can show that $f(M)$ is "locally" a submanifold of $M$, but can we further claim it to be just a submanifold?

Comment: @JordanPayette but the result is just a local one which involves the choice of charts, and these charts may not be included in the atlas of $M$ either.

Comment: Well, your thoughts were not that mad... $g$ vanishes precisely on $f(M) \cap U$, so if you could prove that $g$ has constant rank, you would have that $f(M) \cap U$ is the preimage of a constant rank map, hence a manifold...

Comment: @JordanPayette that would be impossible for any point of $f(M)$ that is not its interior point in $M$.

Comment: Well, it is rather typical to consider a maximal atlas on a manifold, that is to consider every charts which are 'compatible' with a given atlas. The constant rank theorem claims the existence of appropriate 'compatible' charts, so I don't see your problem.

As for your other problem, $g$ is defined on a chart $U$, so its derivative at $p \in f(M)$ (seen as a point in $U$) is well defined. Consider the simplest case $M =  R^2$ and $f(x,y) = x$; if you take $U=M$ and $\phi(x,y) = (x,y)$, your map $g(x,y) = y$ is perfectly well defined and we indeed have $f(M) = g^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55213/discussion-between-jordan-payette-and-vim).

Comment: @JordanPayette I've just worked out a hard-core proof, i.e., using the Euclidean version rank theorem to locally identify $f(M)$ with open subsets in $\Bbb R^r$ and yes, it will be much more convenient if we assume a priori that $M$ carries a maximal smooth structure. Nevertheless, I do believe there is a softer approach which can avoid dealing with those nasty charts, though.